# Find the derivative of $\tan$($\sqrt{1 -x}$)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Find the derivative of $\tan$($\sqrt{1 -x}$)

So I know I have to apply the product rule so wouldn't it be

$\sec^x(\sqrt{1-x})+ \sqrt{1-x}$
$\frac{tan(x)}{2}$
but the final answer says $\frac{-sec^2(\sqrt{1-x})}{2\sqrt{1-x}}$.

Comment: This is not your 1st question... more like 119th. Come on.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the product rule but the chain rule which must be used.

Consider $A=\tan(u)$ with $u=\sqrt{1-x}$. So $$\frac{dA}{dx}=\frac{dA}{du}\times \frac{du}{dx}$$ with $$\frac{dA}{du}=\sec ^2(u)=\sec ^2(\sqrt{1-x})$$ $$\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{1-x}}$$ and finally $$\frac{dA}{dx}=-\frac{\sec ^2\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)}{2 \sqrt{1-x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Same as the other answer, with a bit of difference in style.

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{d}{dx}\tan\sqrt{1-x} &=& \frac{d\tan\sqrt{1-x}}{d\sqrt{1-x}}\cdot\frac{d\sqrt{1-x}}{d (1-x)}\cdot\frac{d(1-x)}{dx}\\
&=&\frac{\sec^2\sqrt{1-x}}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x}}\cdot(-1)\\
&=&\frac{-\sec^2\sqrt{1-x}}{2\sqrt{1-x}}\end{array}$$

Note that the substitutions $v=1-x$ and $u=\sqrt{v}$ were't made explicitily, but they were understood.